# Get selected text from textarea without javascript

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to do something very basic, I have a textarea and a button, once that button is pressed i want to get the selected text from text and possibly put some other characters around it.

I am creating a basic text editor so i will need to be able to do caret position, selected text etc.
I know I can do javascript interop to do this but I am hoping there is a way to do it without javascript

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be done. While you can get the selection change event to fire server side:

```
<textarea @onselect=select></textarea>

@{ 
    void select()
    {
    }
}
```

And you can pass EventArgs into this they don't give you any info as to what the selection itself is. There are seemingly no events args that would help either :[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to get selected text area value without javascript

```
     <div class="row  text-field-container" style="height:150px>
                <MatTextField Required="true" @bind-Value="@Address"
            Class="col-md-12" Outlined="true" TextArea="true" PlaceHolder="Permanent Address"
            Label="Permanent Address">
            </MatTextField>
          </div>
    <div>

    <div>
         <button class="btn btn-outline-primary offset-md-6 col-md-2" @onclick="@Save">
                                    Save
                                </button>
        </div>

@code {
       public string Address{get;set;}
       void Save(){
       var textAreaValue = Address;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Is this answer was helpful? @Zoinky

Comment: This is possibly the least helpful answer I have ever seen on stack overflow. Congrats.